# wordpress theme on subdomain not working

Tags: wordpress

I tried to copy my local wordpress theme on a subdomain of a domain I have.
It gives me the "500 error".

I updated the database and config files to the correct settings.
Still no succes,

Next I copied a clean wordpress copy on the subdomain.
Installed it with the correct database settings
Still no succes.

What happens is, that the subdomain-name changes after I hit enter.
So, my website adres is something like: http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com
after hitting enter, it changes to http://mysubdomain
That's it, the domain name is removed, could that be working, or is that the error I am dealing with?

Any ideas are welcome

Created a new .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: May be its problem of htaccess. You Should Check it once.

Comment: I removed it, and saved permalinks to create a new one, no succes

Comment: try the following: settings ->permalinks -> click save